Custom calendar week number
Suppose I have a calendar that goes from April-April. Using R, how do I find out which week number (e.g. 1-52) a date belongs to?
Here is some data:
example_df <- data.frame(
    full_date = as.Date(c("2020-04-01", "2020-04-08", "2021-03-25", "2021-04-02"))
)

I thought of this way which pushes all dates back to January and then recalculates:
    library(lubridate)
    

example_df %>%
  mutate(
    date_obj = as.Date(full_date),
    fiscal_year = ifelse(month(date_obj) < 4, year(date_obj) - 1, year(date_obj)),
    fiscal_year_start = as.Date(paste0(fiscal_year, "-04-01")),
    days_since_fy_start = as.numeric(date_obj - fiscal_year_start),
    fiscal_week = ceiling((days_since_fy_start + 1) / 7)
  )

Is there another way to do this in R?

    get_april_year <- function(dates) {
      dates <- as.Date(dates)
      
      calendar_year <- as.numeric(format(dates, "%Y"))
      month <- as.numeric(format(dates, "%m"))
      
    
      start_year <- ifelse(month < 4, calendar_year - 1, calendar_year)
      
      fiscal_year <- paste0(start_year, "-", start_year + 1)
      
      return(fiscal_year)
    }

test_dates <- as.Date(c("2020-06-02", "2025-02-15", "2020-04-01"))
get_april_year (test_dates)


#sql equivalent

SELECT 
    full_date,

    CASE 
        WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM full_date) <= 3 THEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM full_date) + 9
        ELSE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM full_date) - 3
    END AS fiscal_month,
    

    CASE 
        WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM full_date) <= 3 
        THEN (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM full_date) - 1) || '-' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM full_date)
        ELSE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM full_date) || '-' || (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM full_date) + 1)
    END AS fiscal_year,

    CASE 
        WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM full_date) <= 3 
        THEN CEIL((full_date - DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM full_date) - 1 || '-04-01')) / 7.0)
        ELSE CEIL((full_date - DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM full_date) || '-04-01')) / 7.0)
    END AS fiscal_week_number
FROM t;

WHERE regexp_like(col1, '^[0-9]+$|^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$');


Update
Now I got your point that you want to start the "year" from a given date, then probably you could use
> as.integer(full_date - full_date[1]) %/% 7 + 1
[1]  1  2 52 53


Previous
You can use %V to present the week number
> full_date <- as.Date(c("2020-04-01", "2020-04-08", "2021-03-25", "2021-04-02"))

> format(full_date, "%V")
[1] "14" "15" "12" "13"

If you type ?strptime, you will see other similar options, e.g., %U and %W, which depends on what you really need.

thank you! but 2020-04-01 is the first week of the april-april calendar

@nov62024 see my update and hope it is what you are after

thank you! last question ... is it possible to get the year in this format, e.g. 2020-2021 ? I wrote some code but I am not sure if its correct

today was a very long coding day lol! if you look at my previous question, I spent so long trying to convert covid data from different time formats lol!

btw  i accepted your answer ! :)

@nov62024 you can parse the year data by format(full_date, "%Y")

is this correct? as.integer(full_date - full_date[1]) %/% 7 + 1 ... dont we need to say example_df$full_date?

@nov62024 yes, you are right you should use example_df$full_date. I just use full_date for short

thank you for the clarification! I see that in your example there can be 53 weeks?
